# No permission to save image but UIActivityViewController completion return no error

Tags: ios

I have this code

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.imageView.image] applicationActivities:nil];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler completionHandlerBlock = ^void(NSString * __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * __nullable returnedItems, NSError * __nullable activityError) {

    if (activityType == UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll && completed) {
        [EkoAlertService presentAlertOnViewController:weakSelf
                                            withTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"save_photo_dialog_title", nil)
                                              message:NSLocalizedString(@"save_photo_dialog_message", nil)
                                           completion:nil];
    }
};

[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:completionHandlerBlock];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

It works fine in the case when user click allow permission to `Save Image`, but when they click don't allow permission I expect it to return some error but `activityError` is nil and I have no way to check whether you successfully save image to camera roll. Both cases return `completed = YES`

Is there a way to check this?

Thanks

Comment: I ran into this same problem. Seems to be an open issue. Found the radar report: https://openradar.appspot.com/34024478

Comment: I believe the only way to check this, for the time being, would be to call 'UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum ' (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum?language=objc) and see if it fails due to permissions not granted.